# TextBox только для цифровых значений

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Собственно задача такая: нужен `TextBox`, в который можно вводить только числа, включая дробные. Если была введена запятая, заменить ее точкой.

Для этой цели я создал кастомный TextBox, в котором проверяю и корректирую ввод. И все работает вроде бы хорошо, пока не задать свойство `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как ее победить.

**Кастомный TextBox**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (char c in e.Text)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(c))
                    continue;

                if ((c == '.' || c == ',') && Text.IndexOf('.') == -1)
                {
                    AppendText(".");
                    SelectionStart = Text.Length;
                }

                e.Handled = true;
            }

            base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Code behind**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public double? D1 { get; set; }
        public double? D2 { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="188" Width="356">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Работает хорошо" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <local:NumericTextBox x:Name="txt1" Height="23" Margin="10,31,218,103" Text="{Binding D1}" Width="120"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Работает не правильно, если UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="44"/>
        <local:NumericTextBox x:Name="txt2" Height="23" Margin="10,103,218,31" Text="{Binding D2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете неправильно. Пользователь должен иметь право вводить любой текст, но текст, не являющийся числом, должен проваливать валидацию.

Затем, замена запятой на точку — ужас. Вы поддерживаете лишь два формата чисел, и игнорируете настройки пользователя. Правильно делать так: вы должны попытаться распарсить текст как число *в текущей локали*, таким образом вы будете поддерживать кастомные настройки пользователя автоматически.

Comment: "Пользователь должен иметь право вводить любой текст" -- спорно. Не зря же придумали специализированные контролы, типа UpDown, DateTimePicker, InputScope в Винфоне и т.д. Почему бы сразу пользователю не показать, что тут можно вводить только данные определенного формата?

Comment: А вот замена разделителя -- действительно грубость :).

Comment: VladD, не могли бы вы показать пример, как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: @andreycha: Ну, допустим, если у меня в буфере `5,7 мм рт. ст.`, или там `4.08.2015`, то я хочу запэйстить весь текст, увидеть его там с красной рамкой, отредактировать, и красная рамка должна при этом пропасть. Если запейстить «5 м/с²», и вместо этого увидеть «52», или например в буфере «(1; 0; 5,2)» превращается в «105,2», то это выглядит не очень правильно.